# Replace the usual fancy header rule with a custom horizontal line

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, rules

The fancy package in LaTeX produces the usual horizontal rule [image: horizontal rule]

Using the graphicx package and the code below, [image]

one can produce the following custom line using the command `\EnglischeLinie`: [image]
The color of the line comes from adding `\textcolor{cyan}{EnglischeLinie}`.
Is there a way to replace the usual fancy header rule in first image with the custom horizontal rule in the third image using the code provided, please? Thank you. Here is the source code

Comment: Please post the source code itself, not a screenshot of the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would say

```
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\smash{\resizebox{0.95\linewidth}{0.4ex}{\textcolor{cyan}{%
    \fontsize{20}{24}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}{4}}}}}
```

The `\smash` is to make sure that it doesn't take vertical space.
I have taken out the `center` environment because that doesn't work inside the `\headrule`.

Comment: What do I do to have the line drawn? I have added your code, but I do not see any changes to the header

Comment: It has worked. Thank you